# How can I make this script not consume so much? Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, optimization

i'm making a mobile game and I need certain elements to follow a circuit so I download a Unity asset. It turns out that once everything is assembled, it is consuming 37% of the FPS. Then I looked at the comments and there was a person who warned about that and that a certain script is the one that works badly because it uses old transformations and that in less than 10 minutes the performance had improved by 10. I have looked in the profiler and indeed it is the script that mentions the one that is consuming the FPS. I've fixed this script but I can't get it, I'm pretty new to this. If anyone has any ideas on how to fix this it would be a great help. Thank you very much in advance.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

namespace PathCreation.Utility {
public static class MathUtility {

    static PosRotScale LockTransformToSpace (Transform t, PathSpace space) {
        var original = new PosRotScale (t);
        if (space == PathSpace.xy) {
            t.eulerAngles = new Vector3 (0, 0, t.eulerAngles.z);
            t.position = new Vector3 (t.position.x, t.position.y, 0);
        } else if (space == PathSpace.xz) {
            t.eulerAngles = new Vector3 (0, t.eulerAngles.y, 0);
            t.position = new Vector3 (t.position.x, 0, t.position.z);
        }

        //float maxScale = Mathf.Max (t.localScale.x * t.parent.localScale.x, t.localScale.y * t.parent.localScale.y, t.localScale.z * t.parent.localScale.z);
        float maxScale = Mathf.Max (t.lossyScale.x, t.lossyScale.y, t.lossyScale.z);

        t.localScale = Vector3.one * maxScale;

        return original;
    }

    public static Vector3 TransformPoint (Vector3 p, Transform t, PathSpace space) {
        var original = LockTransformToSpace (t, space);
        Vector3 transformedPoint = t.TransformPoint (p);
        original.SetTransform (t);
        return transformedPoint;
    }

    public static Vector3 InverseTransformPoint (Vector3 p, Transform t, PathSpace space) {
        var original = LockTransformToSpace (t, space);
        Vector3 transformedPoint = t.InverseTransformPoint (p);
        original.SetTransform (t);
        return transformedPoint;
    }

    public static Vector3 TransformVector (Vector3 p, Transform t, PathSpace space) {
        var original = LockTransformToSpace (t, space);
        Vector3 transformedPoint = t.TransformVector (p);
        original.SetTransform (t);
        return transformedPoint;
    }

    public static Vector3 InverseTransformVector (Vector3 p, Transform t, PathSpace space) {
        var original = LockTransformToSpace (t, space);
        Vector3 transformedPoint = t.InverseTransformVector (p);
        original.SetTransform (t);
        return transformedPoint;
    }

    public static Vector3 TransformDirection (Vector3 p, Transform t, PathSpace space) {
        var original = LockTransformToSpace (t, space);
        Vector3 transformedPoint = t.TransformDirection (p);
        original.SetTransform (t);
        return transformedPoint;
    }

    public static Vector3 InverseTransformDirection (Vector3 p, Transform t, PathSpace space) {
        var original = LockTransformToSpace (t, space);
        Vector3 transformedPoint = t.InverseTransformDirection (p);
        original.SetTransform (t);
        return transformedPoint;
    }

    public static bool LineSegmentsIntersect (Vector2 a1, Vector2 a2, Vector2 b1, Vector2 b2) {
        float d = (b2.x - b1.x) * (a1.y - a2.y) - (a1.x - a2.x) * (b2.y - b1.y);
        if (d == 0)
            return false;
        float t = ((b1.y - b2.y) * (a1.x - b1.x) + (b2.x - b1.x) * (a1.y - b1.y)) / d;
        float u = ((a1.y - a2.y) * (a1.x - b1.x) + (a2.x - a1.x) * (a1.y - b1.y)) / d;

        return t >= 0 && t <= 1 && u >= 0 && u <= 1;
    }

    public static bool LinesIntersect (Vector2 a1, Vector2 a2, Vector2 a3, Vector2 a4) {
        return (a1.x - a2.x) * (a3.y - a4.y) - (a1.y - a2.y) * (a3.x - a4.x) != 0;
    }

    public static Vector2 PointOfLineLineIntersection (Vector2 a1, Vector2 a2, Vector2 a3, Vector2 a4) {
        float d = (a1.x - a2.x) * (a3.y - a4.y) - (a1.y - a2.y) * (a3.x - a4.x);
        if (d == 0) {
            Debug.LogError ("Lines are parallel, please check that this is not the case before calling line intersection method");
            return Vector2.zero;
        } else {
            float n = (a1.x - a3.x) * (a3.y - a4.y) - (a1.y - a3.y) * (a3.x - a4.x);
            float t = n / d;
            return a1 + (a2 - a1) * t;
        }
    }

    public static Vector2 ClosestPointOnLineSegment (Vector2 p, Vector2 a, Vector2 b) {
        Vector2 aB = b - a;
        Vector2 aP = p - a;
        float sqrLenAB = aB.sqrMagnitude;

        if (sqrLenAB == 0)
            return a;

        float t = Mathf.Clamp01 (Vector2.Dot (aP, aB) / sqrLenAB);
        return a + aB * t;
    }

    public static Vector3 ClosestPointOnLineSegment (Vector3 p, Vector3 a, Vector3 b) {
        Vector3 aB = b - a;
        Vector3 aP = p - a;
        float sqrLenAB = aB.sqrMagnitude;

        if (sqrLenAB == 0)
            return a;

        float t = Mathf.Clamp01 (Vector3.Dot (aP, aB) / sqrLenAB);
        return a + aB * t;
    }

    public static int SideOfLine (Vector2 a, Vector2 b, Vector2 c) {
        return (int) Mathf.Sign ((c.x - a.x) * (-b.y + a.y) + (c.y - a.y) * (b.x - a.x));
    }

    /// returns the smallest angle between ABC. Never greater than 180
    public static float MinAngle (Vector3 a, Vector3 b, Vector3 c) {
        return Vector3.Angle ((a - b), (c - b));
    }

    public static bool PointInTriangle (Vector2 a, Vector2 b, Vector2 c, Vector2 p) {
        float area = 0.5f * (-b.y * c.x + a.y * (-b.x + c.x) + a.x * (b.y - c.y) + b.x * c.y);
        float s = 1 / (2 * area) * (a.y * c.x - a.x * c.y + (c.y - a.y) * p.x + (a.x - c.x) * p.y);
        float t = 1 / (2 * area) * (a.x * b.y - a.y * b.x + (a.y - b.y) * p.x + (b.x - a.x) * p.y);
        return s >= 0 && t >= 0 && (s + t) <= 1;
    }

    public static bool PointsAreClockwise (Vector2[] points) {
        float signedArea = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < points.Length; i++) {
            int nextIndex = (i + 1) % points.Length;
            signedArea += (points[nextIndex].x - points[i].x) * (points[nextIndex].y + points[i].y);
        }

        return signedArea >= 0;
    }

    class PosRotScale {
        public readonly Vector3 position;
        public readonly Quaternion rotation;
        public readonly Vector3 scale;

        public PosRotScale (Transform t) {
            this.position = t.position;
            this.rotation = t.rotation;
            this.scale = t.localScale;
        }

        public void SetTransform (Transform t) {
            t.position = position;
            t.rotation = rotation;
            t.localScale = scale;

        }
    }
}
}
```

[Here I leave some images of the profiler](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1NbENriw0EBvnOUbW8KGHdNgNR52peaK4?usp=sharing)

Comment: There are many methods in this class. It would be good to include more detailed Profiler information so people can know which method(s) in particular are the bottleneck.

Comment: What does _"it is consuming 37% of the FPS"_ even mean? FPS is not something that can be consumed! Do you mean the FPS drops by 37%.

Answer (score 0):

One easy optimization would be to get rid of the PosRotScale class. Now every time that LockTransformToSpace is called it allocates a new instance of the class. You could instead store the original position, rotation and scale individually before calling LockTransformToSpace and then restore them afterwards individually as well.

**Update**: Here's an example of what I mean:

```
public static Vector3 InverseTransformPoint(Vector3 p, Transform t, PathSpace space)
{
    var originalPosition = t.position;
    var originalRotation = t.rotation;
    var originalScale = t.localScale;

    LockTransformToSpace(t, space);
    Vector3 transformedPoint = t.InverseTransformPoint(p);
    
    t.position = originalPosition;
    t.rotation = originalRotation;
    t.localScale = originalScale;

    return transformedPoint;
}
```

Comment: How can I do to save it as a variable? As much as I try I can't get it even if I set it to static. I have edited the first message by adding more detailed pictures of the profiler.

Comment: Hi, at the end i start deleting thinks and see if keep working, and i delete almost the entire script and still working and with better perfosmance, but thx